# Convert to toLocaleString date to new Date format

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a condition where i'm converting date format according to `toLocaleString`.

`const localDate = proDate.toLocaleString("en-GB").replace(/,/g, "");`

here proDate is a `new Date(someDate)` object.

Later in my code i need to convert `localDate` to `new Date()` format.

I'm trying to pass `new Date(localDate)` but getting as invalid date.

The `localDate` format is `18/03/2023 08:45:47`.

Here in my code when i'm trying to convert `localDate` i dont have access to proDate.

Is any workaround for this.

Comment: You're much better off to store *someDate* or its time value as the output from *toLocaleString* is not guaranteed to be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse it with a regular expression since you know the format.

```js
const localDate = new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB").replace(/,/g, "");
console.log(localDate);
const [, day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds] = localDate.match(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
const date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes, seconds)
console.log(date);
```

Alternatively, as [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182) suggested, it suffices to only match consecutive digits in this case:

```js
const localDate = new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB").replace(/,/g, "");
const [day, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds] = localDate.match(/\d+/g);
const date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes, seconds)
console.log(date);
```

Comment: The regular expression could be just `/\d+/g`, and remove the elision from the assignment array before *day*. ;-).